# Zooming in UIScrollView - Unable to zoom beyond single image and scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an array of images loading from the NSURL to scroll in and pinch zoom. I was able to implement the scroll part but when I try to zoom any image beyond the first one, the scroll is stuck and so is the scale on the image. Here is my code:

```
 scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, SCREEN_WIDTH, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


for (int i=0; i<[listOfImagesZoom count]; i++) {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftMargin, self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y-100, SCREEN_WIDTH, self.view.bounds.size.height-100)];
    // [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_def.png"]];
    NSString *urlImage1 = (NSString*)[listOfImagesZoom objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *productImageURL1 = [urlImage1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~" withString:@""];
    NSString *productImageURL2 = [productImageURL1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString* urlImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sagana-ideas.azurewebsites.net%@", productImageURL2];
    NSURL *imgURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlImage];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ex_product.png"]];

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    imageView.tag = i;

    leftMargin += SCREEN_WIDTH;


}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(leftMargin, 0)];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

I have even implemented the

```
 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

    {

        return imageView;
    }
```

It works if there is only single image to load, but is stuck when there is more than 1 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ScrollView to display list of your images. Each image was displayed a scrollView(a subclass scrollview) to perform zoom in/out. 
Try to look at this: [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIView inside scrollview in which you may add your all images and then return that view from, `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method.

Comment: Even tried with using UIview as a container and adding that as a subview to my scrollview. Same result

Comment: You will have to set height of inner view to the total height of all images.